# Clicking an input checkbox in internet explorer

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer, input

I'm trying to simply check "Yes" on an internet explorer input checkbox if the user clicks "Yes" to a MsgBox popup, or do nothing if the user clicks "No" on the MsgBox. No matter what I try, the code just doesn't seem to click the button I want it to click.

My code is as follows:

```
strPrompt = "Please look to see if this client has a valid brokerage account available for enrollment. Would you like to enroll this client in FRT service and submit a ticket?"
strTitle = "User Input Required"



iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
    If iRet = vbYes Then
        Enrollment_Button = objIE.document.getElementsById("classActionFlagReq")
        Enrollment_Button.Value = "Y"
    Else
        MsgBox "No"
    End If
```

I will also include the HTML source where the Yes and No buttons are contained:

```
<SPAN class=radio2>
<input name="classActionFlagReq" class="radio2" type="radio" value="Y"></input>
</span>
<SPAN class=radio2>
<input name="classActionFlagReq" class="radio2" type="radio" value="N"></input>
</span>
```

Where am I going wrong?
Updated Edited Code:

```
iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
    If iRet = vbYes Then
        Set Enrollment_Button = objIE.document.getElementById("classActionFlagReq")
        Enrollment_Button.Checked = True
    Else
        MsgBox "No"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few issues.

1. It's `getElementById()`, not `getElementsById()`.
2. `getElementById()` returns an object. Use `Set`.

   ```
   Set Enrollment_Button = objIE.document.getElementById("classActionFlagReq")
   ```
3. Use the `Checked` property to set a checkbox or radio button, not `Value="Y"`.

   ```
   Enrollment_Button.Checked = True
   ```
4. You're using the same `name` for both radio buttons, which is fine (that's how you define a radio "group") but if you want to access an individual radio button (so that you can select it), you need to assign a unique ID (or use a different selector method, like `getElementsByName`).

Comment: I just made a change to the bottom of the OP. It's still not checking any boxes though. Should I add a (0) to the end of the variable to specify the first one?

Comment: Try assigning one an `id` attribute and see if your script can find it. I would think you'd be getting an error. You don't have `On Error Resume Next` declared, right?

Comment: Just add `id="mytest"` to one of your `<input>` elements and then use `getElementById("mytest")`.

Comment: You're right, I did have an error handler enabled. I just disabled it and the error brings me to the "Enrollment_Button.Checked = True" statement telling me that the object doesn't support this property or method. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you mean with assigning an ID attribute to a variable. I'm new to VBA. I googled this and didn't find much.

Comment: Try using a specific ID, as I mentioned above. `Checked = True` should work. See the docs for a radio button [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769160(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So here's what's interesting. In my code there is a command that pushes a button that opens a child window at some point. To handle this child window I use SendKeys to close it and then the page the code was originally working on refreshes. When this happens, it seems like my code stops working all together. The bubble is not getting checked so I tried just typing in a simple text box and that didn't work either. I keep getting the same error no matter what I try to change "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Try it without the extra stuff -- the child window and the page refresh, etc. If you just click a button that checks the radio button, does it work? If so, this question is answered and you should probably submit a new question for your other issue.

Comment: I deleted all extraneous information in the macro (a completely new workbook actually). Now it just loads the site up and tries to click the button. I get the same error. When I add the id="mytest" as an attribute to the html, it is lost on a page refresh.

Comment: Figured it out with the help of this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559408/using-vba-to-operate-radio-buttons-on-a-web-page.
Thank you for all of your help and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

The properties `name` and `id` aren't interchangeable. You don't have any element with an `id` equal to "classActionFlagReq", so `getElementsById` is not finding any elements.

Note that `id` is unique, so you won't just be able to set both `input`s to the same `id` like you did with the `name`s.

Comment: Actually, IE will automatically create the ID's for all named elements, so he should be fine there (even if by accident).

Comment: So I just changed the code to "Enrollment_Button = objIE.document.getElementsByName("classActionFlagReq")" but I'm still not getting any luck. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ieRadio = objIE.document.all
ieRadio.Item("classActionFlagReq")(1).Checked = True
```

This solved my issue!