# How do I select a radio button on an Internet Explorer page using VBA?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to open a website and select a radio button using VBA.  My error message reads "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed".

The ID of the button I am trying to click is : id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnRequestForSomeoneElse

Here is my VBA:

```
Sub Upload()

Dim url As String
url = "http://radiobuttonlocation.com"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate url

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop


IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnRequestForSomeoneElse").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Would specifying element number help?
`IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnRequestForSomeoneElse")(0).Click`

Or maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575863/7077298

Comment: Doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So IE tends to Lose itself when it navigates,  Try to obtain the webpage again.

*This requires a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation, Microsoft Internet Controls

```
Sub Upload()

Dim url As String
url = "http://radiobuttonlocation.com"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate url

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
'get the webpage again
set IE = GetWebPage(url)

IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnRequestForSomeoneElse").Click


End Sub


Public Function GetWebPage(sUrl As String) As InternetExplorer
Dim winShell As Shell
Dim dt As Date
dt = DateAdd("s", 300, DateTime.Now)

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Do While dt > DateTime.Now
    Set winShell = New Shell
    'loop through the windows and check the internet explorer windows
    For Each ie In winShell.Windows
    If ie.LocationURL = sUrl Then

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Silent = True
        Set GetWebPage = ie

        Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
        Loop
        Exit Do

    Set winShell = Nothing
    End If
    Next ie
    Set winShell = Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting "Complie error:  User-defined type not defined" as soon as I call the Public Function.

Comment: Did you add the references listed in the answer? *This requires a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation, Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: My bad.  Thought I had.  Works great.  Thank you!